# Cannot upvote on a site where I'm not a user

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, user-experience

Screenshot: http://i40.tinypic.com/2i0arft.png

Today I tried to upvote a question on Arqade, where I haven't signed up. I reached the question from the "welcome" page. I haven't been able to do so, a red bar with an error message appears.

The expected behaviour would be to show the login page (in order to create an account on Arqade).

Comment: The web UI shows a popup inviting you to sign up or log in in that case, so +1.

Comment: What's the problem? You don't have an account there. So what you see is [meta-tag:status-bydesign]...

Comment: The problem is that I can access a site with the app but cannot sign up or sign in the same way as the web.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this!

I spent a good chunk of the last month adding this functionality in and I forgot to enable it for non-debug builds. This has been fixed and is in version 1.0.1 propagating right now, meaning you should receive the update anytime between now and 2 hours from now.

Comment: Wow, impressive fix time! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for reporting it! I wouldn't have caught this since I'm still using the internal debug builds.